# Networking frustrations - 2 weeks of research with no answers

Tags: networking, mount, samba, sharing

I have three computers on my network.  1 Windows 10 machine, 1 Mac OS machine and 1 Ubuntu machine.

Windows machine: can see Mac, access Mac, read and write to Mac.  Can see Ubuntu machine but trying to access with credentials fails.

Mac machine: can see Windows machine, access Windows, read and write to Windows.  Can see Ubuntu machine but fails to access with credentials.

Linux machine: can see Mac machine in browser but I get asked for username and password an infinite amount of times with no progress.  Can see network folder called Windows network but not machines within that folder.  I can ping both other computers successfully. I can mount each computer using:

mount -t cifs '\192.168.0.XX\XXXX' /home/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX -o username=XXXX,password=XXXX

However, I cannot write to the drives once I have them mounted.

My smbtree looks like this:

WORKGROUP

\XXX-LINUX    Linux server

\XXX-WINDOWS    Windows

\XXX-MAC    Mac

\AIRPORT-TIME-XX    AirPort Time Capsule

\AIRPORT-TIME-XX\IPC$

My testparm-s looks like this:

Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf

rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)

Processing section "[printers]"

Processing section "[print$]"

Processing section "[Public Directory]"

Processing section "[Private Directory]"

Loaded services file OK.

WARNING: You have some share names that are longer than 12 characters.

These may not be accessible to some older clients.
(Eg. Windows9x, WindowsMe, and smbclient prior to Samba 3.0.)

Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Global parameters

[global]

```
server string = %h server

security = USER

log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

max log size = 1000

name resolve order = wins lmhosts hosts bcast

printcap name = cups

dns proxy = No

client ipc signing = No

idmap config * : backend = tdb

hosts allow = 192.168.0.

hosts deny = ALL
```

[printers]

```
path = /var/spool/samba

printable = Yes

browseable = No
```

[print$]

```
path = /var/lib/samba/printers
```

[Public Directory]

```
path = /Public/Files

read only = No

guest ok = Yes
```

[Private Directory]

```
path = /private/files/

valid users = me

browseable = No
```

My samba is up to date I believe and correctly configured on the other two computers I believe (they are interacting with each other via samba as well).

My /etc/hosts looks like this:

127.0.1.1 XXX-linux

127.0.0.1 localhost

192.168.0.XX XXX-desktop

192.168.0.XX XXX-mac

The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts

::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback

fe00::0 ip6-localnet

ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix

ff02::1 ip6-allnodes

ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

I really am just looking for this computer to have the same read/write access to the other two computers, using the same logins, as the other two  enjoy.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

[1] Always post what version of Ubuntu you are using. Samba - both client and server - on Ubuntu 18.04 works differently from Ubuntu 16.04 for example.

[2] Your smb.conf is not configured correctly for many reasons. The most obvious is your private share is not browseable: `browseable = No`.

[3] If you can access the share with a manual mount you need to take possession of the mount when mounting so you have access and not just root:

For a Windows share:

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.0.XX/XXXX /home/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX -o username=XXXX,password=XXXX,uid=1000
```

For a MacOS share:

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.0.XX/XXXX /home/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX -o username=XXXX,password=XXXX,uid=1000,nounix
```

*Change 1000 to your own uid number which can be found by running the following command:*

```
id
```

[4] Your private share lists `valid users = me`

There is no such user as "me". Change it to your real user name - let's say it's robert. Then add that user to the samba password database:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a robert
```

[5] There is a copy of the factory default smb.conf at /usr/share/samba/smb.conf in case you want to start over.

[6] If there were ever a question that should be asked in the ubuntu forum it's this one. AskUbuntu doesn't lend itself to multiple posts required to troubleshoot this type of samba question.

Comment: Okay.  Thank you for the detailed and thoughtful response.  I was so happy with level of detail I provided and then stupidly left off the main point. I will try tonight.  I was unsure about here or the forum but I appreciate that tip.

Comment: Okay, I applied your recommendations but to no avail.  However, I will follow your advice and take it to a more appropriate venue than AskUbuntu.  Thanks.

Comment: You said in your original post that you address your share this way: '\192.168.0.XX\XXXX' and you stated that works. I don't see how it could have so I edited my post to reflect how it should be done: //192.168.0.XX/XXXX